# Properties window like visual studio in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

there is a design panel like XAML designer that i added some Controls on it(in run-time with create instance of some element and add it to `RootLayout.Children`). now i like manipulate some properties of one control(that i now which one) with something like this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://meysamjavadi.persiangig.com/props.png))</sub>

is there a any short approach to goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search for [+`PropertyGrid` +Silverlight](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=propertygrid+silverlight) suggests things like [this](http://slpropertygrid.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://slg30.codeplex.com/).

Comment: i select ComponentOne PropertyGrid.